# Recovering from a lost unmanaged solution in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am in the unfortunate situation of having lost the **unmanaged** solution for our production environment in **`Dynamics 365`**. What I do have is an export of the **managed** solution that I am able to inspect.

I had tried to manually modify the managed solution to be unmanaged by updating `<Managed>1</Managed>` to **0**. However when importing this modified solution into the same environment, the import failed with the message

> "unmanaged solution expects full formXml" (error code 0x8004023B)

It's worth noting that I was attempting to import the modified unmanaged solution into an environment where the managed equivalent was already installed and in-use. I am not sure if importing this manually unmanaged solution into a fresh environment would be successful.

---

**Questions:**

> 1. What are my options in recovering an unmanaged and editable solution from this exported managed solution?
> 2. If an unmanaged solution is able to be recovered and installed in Sandbox, will there by any issues in updating the managed solution in
>      Production?
> 3. Is it possibly to simply add on a new solution, dependent on the base managed solution, that would allow me to modify the base
>      solution? I am pretty sure I can add features to the base solution but
>      would not be able to change or remove any features of the base
>      solution.
> 4. Would importing this modified unmanaged solution into a fresh environment have a better chance of importing without error?

Comment: After contacting Dynamics 365 support they have recommended rebuilding the solution from scratch. While this is the official solution I am still interested in other potential (and unsupported) solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out thi article on how to manipulate solutions via SDK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/sample-work-solutions

You shuld be able to re-create the unmanage solution though this.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Solution Packager
  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/compress-extract-solution-file-solutionpackager)
  to extract your solution as managed.
- In extracted folder in file Other\Solution.xml change Managed to 0.
- Use Solution Packager to pack your solution as unmanaged
  (/packagetype:Unmanaged) Import it into development organization.
- Verify that all your customizations are there and valid.

No guarantees but it should work. You might loose some managed changes for forms and sitemaps. Most probably you aren't using them.

Also please do organization backups before importing solutions into your organizations. Just in case something won't go as expected.